Master Thesis Positions in Germany without University Affiliations
I live in Germany and want to pursue a PhD degree in Biology/Bioinformatics/....
I already have a Master's degree from outside the EU. However, it did not have a thesis or a research component. I do have practical experience as I have worked in a leading cancer hospital as a pathology lab technician.
As most PhD roles require a thesis and/or research experience. I'm finding some "Master Thesis" openings. Can I apply to them directly to bridge my thesis & research gap? Is it acceptable that I am not currently a student and not affiliated with any university here? If yes, how does it work?

I am pretty sure you have to be a) enrolled at a university to be eligible for such a position and b) might even need to proof that you have already amassed enough masters credits for some of them.

There is no such thing as "Master thesis position" in Germany (as far as I am aware of). If you want to pursue a Master's from Germany you have to enroll in a study program. There is no way to just work a Master's thesis without the study (at least I have never heard of such a thing - the universities where I have been certainly do not offer such a thing).

There are master Thesis positions in the sense that research institutions or industry will offer the opportunity to write the thesis with them on a specific topic they want to have looked into. But to actually get such a position you have to be an enrolled master's student.

True. But, as you said, such a thing is neither sufficient nor necessary to be able to write a master's thesis. Also "position" may not be the right word here as one can not be paid for a master's thesis

Sometime an topic by a company comes with an additional opportunity for an internship in parallel, but being paid by a company for writing a thesis is not allowed in  Germany.

You first need to figure out how much of your non-EU masters degree is recognized in Germany. It could be recognized as equivalent to a masters degree, equivalent to a bachelors degree or not recognized as an academic degree at all. This depends on a lot of details so I can't give a general answer here.
Next, knowing what degree you have from a German standpoint, you can apply for a suitable continuation eventually leading to a PhD. Note that only universities or applied universities (Fachhochschulen) are allowed to give out masters degrees or PHDs, so you will have to apply at one of these.

My Masters is fully equivalent to a German masters degree. Even though it doesn’t contain a research track

@mjalajel The question is not whether you or I consider it equivalent, the question is whether the German government does. The fact that it does not contain a research track may mean it doesn't but I don't know. If it does you can apply to a PhD program at a university the same way someone with a German masters degree could. That is the point of saying they are equivalent.

@mjalajel And if they really are considered equivalent officially, I am pretty sure that you might well be able to find a PhD position as is. Germany isn't the US, it is often much more important that you fulfill the requirements on paper (in this case hold a valid MA degree with good/very good grades) and show interest and enthusiasm than already have a ton of research experience.
